# Django @method_decorator change from Python 2 to 3?

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, migration

I am currently working on the migration from Python 2 to 3 of my code. I use Django and it looks like i am missing something.

I am using the decorator @method_decorator(func) from Django. my function is define like that :

```
@decorator
func(action_meth, *args, **kwargs):
    result = action_meth(*args, **kwargs)
    # do 
    # something
    # with 
    # result
```

My problem is that the value of args from Python 2 and Python 3 is not the same and then args cannot be use as arguments for my action_meth (i get the error : *action_meth takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given*)

So first, this code work fine in Python 2. But i cant find any thing concerning the Python 3 migration on internet.
Also i am quiet sure it comes from Djangos method_decorator... so does anyone knows if anything has changed concerning this features?

Here is a sample of what i can get,

In Python 2 :
print(args) => `([u'ID'],)`

In Python 3 :
print(args) => `SELECT fieldA,fieldB, ...., fieldZ ....; args=(ID,)`

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed, this was an other problem deeper in the code.

Also sory for the bad formulation of the question!